# How to fetch value from text field to java in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

How do I add the functionality of producing text fields based on user input for number of ingredients.

```
 Number of Ingredients:<input id="noIngred" type="numbename="noIngred">
<fmt:parseNumber var="intValue" value="${noIngred}" integerOnly="true"/>
<c:forEach var="j" begin="1" end="${intValue}">
 <input type="text" name="Ingredient${j}">
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to read all Parameters available in current HTTP request using getParameterNames() API of HttpServletRequest which shall list out all the parameters.

Use regex based matching (sample regex: **"Ingredient[0-9]*"**  ) to filter the parameters starts with "Ingredient" as prefix and suffix with "digits"

Answer (score 0):

You can give all the inputs the same name.

```
 <input type="text" name="Ingredient">
```

Then in your servlet, you can get all the values as an array with:

```
String[] ingredients = request.getParameterValues("Ingredient");
```

If you need to send each value with their own name, then you could also send the size of `intValue` to your servlet as a hidden input. And based on the size, get the parameters like this:

```
ArrayList<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int x = 0; x < intValue.size();x++){
String name = "Ingredient"+x;
String ingredient = request.getParameter(name);
...
}
```

Another way you could do it is by getting all the parameters as a map:

```
Map<String, String[]> parameters = request.getParameterMap();
```

To loop through them:

```
for(String parameter : parameters.keySet()) {
    if(parameter.contains("Ingredient")) {
        String[] values = parameters.get(parameter);
        ...
    }
}
```